# Is there a way to call a React Native function from Native Android Code?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

Looking for a way to call a React Native function from Native Android Code.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

check this in react native documentation.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/communication-ios#calling-react-native-functions-from-native-events

once you created the custom native component you can trigger events and process those in react native.

ios: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-ios#events

android: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android#events